# JSF Composite Component Netbeans

Tags: jsf, netbeans

I'm tried to develop jsf composite component but netbeans ide complaints the no library found for this namespace.

xmlns:cform="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/cform"

What is the error about ? Where should i put the composite component (which folder) ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML namespace url is incorrect.  Declaring a namespace like so:

```
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
```

Will result in composite component namespace like `<composite:interface>` for example.

Composite components should be in the `WEB-INF/resources/[foldername]` folder where `[foldername]` is the name of the folder you wish to keep composite components.

You can then reference your composite components in that folder with the following url and providing a given namespace of your choice.  For this example lets say I have a composite component called `avatarGenerator.xhtml` inside of the following folder, `WEB-INF\resources\ptc`.

**The XML Namespace declaration**

```
xmlns:ptc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/ptc"
```

**The use of avatarGenerator**

```
<ptc:avatarGenerator attributeone="" attributetwo="">
```