# Change composite-component's namespace

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, jsf-2.2

I have a small library (JAR) containing some custom JSF-components. Some of them are composite-components which are completely (or partly) implemented in XHTML files which reside under `META-INF/resources/my-components`. To use these components from other XHTML-files I have to use the XML-namespace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/my-components`.

Other related components in this library are implemented as POJOs using `@FacesComponent` (and `@FacesRenderer`). To use these components, I have to use the XML-namespace which is defined at the component's `@FacesComponent`-annotation (attribute `namespace`). At this point I can choose whatever I want (like `http://my-company.com/my-components`).

Since I have not found any possibility to change the namespace-prefix of my composite components, and I do not want to set my POJO's namespace to something like `jcp.org` (I'm not sure if this is even possible), I have to use two different namespaces to use my components coming from the same library.

But since the namespaces are different only because of an implementation-detail and maybe one component will be realized in a different way in the future, this is not what I want.

**So the question is**: is there a way to specify the full namespace for my composite-components? Of course, I want to use the same ones which are used for my other components (`http://my-company.com/my-components` in the example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the composite library name in your `*.taglib.xml` file, below the namespace declaration.

```xml
<namespace>http://my-company.com/my-components</namespace>
<composite-library-name>my-components</composite-library-name>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just hat to add all existing tags to the taglib, which have been created automatically before (using `@FacesComponent(createTag=true, ...)`). But it works as expected and I can use a common namespace.